# When a comment is removed unjustly

Tags: discussion, support

Comments are not intended for discussion, however they are intended to further make remarks that relate to the questions and answers on any given topic.

These are mostly universal rules of comments on all SE sites.

These rules are not supposed to be restricted to "based on how many comments there are". I get "chat" and "discussion" is not intended to take place as thats what "chat" is for. However often times, an answer as a comment vs an answer as an answer is the appropriate response and this should not be limited to how many answers or comments there are.

Equally there is no rule that specifically restricts comments to "only for remarks that will help others understand the question better or to ask clarification questions".

That said, why do people on parenting.SE not seem to understand that?

I for the first time ever on any SE child site has a comment removed and told to take it to chat. But it was not a chat type reply. It required no discussion and engaged no one in any way. The reasoning given for why the comment was removed was basically "there are to many comments if we don't remove comments specifically relating to clarifying the question".

At what point do members just get to ignore the rules and intents and just make up their own reasons and logic to the extent of removing comments - and yes I no there is no promise comments will remain and what have you... but this seems outside that scope imo.

Thread my comment was removed from:
[My girlfriend has mentioned disowning her 14 y/o transgender daughter](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/27277/my-girlfriend-has-mentioned-disowning-her-14-y-o-transgender-daughter?noredirect=1#comment53486_27277)

Comment: Actually, your first comment was going to be removed regardless of the number of other comments. It wasn't relevant to the OP's question, but questioned the foundation of his romantic relationship. More importantly, anything that closes with "Wake the hell up", whether Question, Answer, or Comment, isn't really an appropriate tone for our site. My comment was a reply to your _second_ comment which asked you to take your concerns about "why" comments are there to Meta (and thank you for doing so), and was not an explanation for why your first comment was deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange has a general policy which is that comments are to request or give updates, to clarify. Not for discussion or conversation!

This holds especially true on Parenting, where it is all too easy to end up in a long and unconstructive discussion.

Here, we shift them into a chat room or delete them outright. This is a mod role, or if there are too many comments the system will allow normal users to move them to chat.

I'm not sure why you believe that it should be any different. This is [tag: status-by-design]